# AWS Fargate windows container fails to start with "The container operating system does not match the host operating system"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, .net-core, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to deploy a dotnet core windows service on ECS Fargate. I have created an ECS service and a task definition specifying the `Operating system family` for both to be `Windows Server 2019 Core`. However, when the task is run by Fargate, it fails with this message:

```
Status reason   CannotStartContainerError: ResourceInitializationError: failed to create
new container runtime task: failed to create shim: hcs::CreateComputeSystem c41cc2fa7a284f59bb1f8e037cb5b883-3516356657: 
The container operating system does not match the operating system.
```

Service:
[image]

Task definition:
[image]

this is my terraform task definition:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "transform_service" {
  family                   = "${var.app_name}-transform-service-task"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                = 2 * 1024  #2 vCPU
  memory             = 16 * 1024 # 16GB
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.transform_service_task_execution_role.arn

  container_definitions = jsonencode([{
    name      = "transform-service-container-${var.environment}"
    image     = "${var.transform_service_repository_url}:latest"
    essential = true
    environment = [{
      "name" : "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT", "value" : "Development"
    }]
    },
  ])
}
```

I used this docker file to build the image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["myapp.DataTransform.Service/myapp.DataTransform.Service.csproj","NuGet.Config", "myapp.DataTransform.Service/"]
#copy the "NuGet.Config" file insude the container so we can access our devops private nuget feed repository during dotnet restore command
RUN dotnet restore --configfile "myapp.DataTransform.Service/NuGet.Config" "myapp.DataTransform.Service/myapp.DataTransform.Service.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/myapp.DataTransform.Service"
RUN dotnet build "myapp.DataTransform.Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "myapp.DataTransform.Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.DataTransform.Service.dll"]
```

**Note**: the `runtimePlatform` property is not supported yet by terraform, I have specified it manually using the AWS Console after I deployed the task with terraform

Comment: We (AWS container team) have been chatting offline about this. Have you tried (or can you try) to deploy a task that has the base image (`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1`) as its container image? Does that work? One of the speculations is that, given that image is multi-os (and multi-arch), the dockerfile may have been built on a different system which made the resulting downstream image you are using incompatible with the Windows 2019 kernel Fargate supports.

Comment: Hello @mreferre. Sure I can try it but I am a bit confused. I thought I am using the same image as a base image. See `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1 AS base` in my Dockerfile. Also, I have to mention that I build the docker image on Windows, so that might have something to do with it, not sure

Comment: Yes you are using that image as the base but that image seems to be including multiple versions, multiple archs and multiple OSes. So the theory was that you docker built it on a Windows system whose version is incompatible with the Fargate Windows system version (2019) and hence the resulting image can't run (again, it's just a theory). Proving that the base image alone can run on Fargate allows us to rule out the infrastructure setup (we tried to run it and it runs so if you get the same error perhaps it's something not configured properly at the task def level).

Comment: Thank you for the additional info. I understand now what you were suggesting (have only `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1` image deployed to Fargate (windows) and no other layers from my end. I will try to test that when I have a chance and report back. Thanks again :)